# Displaying Json data from example url

Tags: jquery, json

I know this has been asked before, but I'm struggling to see what is wrong with my code here as I'm still getting a blank page:

Jquery is included in the page

(url from http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html)

```
var url="http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
       $.each(data.geonames, function (){
        $('ul#results').append('<li><div class=\"name\">' +this.toponymName+ '</div></li>');
        });
    });
```

I've tried saving the file locally as replacing the url with 'test.json' but nothing there too. Any ideas or syntax I'm missing here?

Comment: It not solution but you need not use \"  .

Comment: For one, you don't need to escape the double quotes in `'<li><div class=\"name\">'`. Use `'<li><div class="name">'` since it is surrounded already by single quotes, not double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the url from your browser: http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

You'll see that the "the hourly limit of 2000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application."